# What's the most reliable solution which can accurately detect an UIWebView on iOS?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

We know many browsers and apps on iOS use UIWebView which is provided by iOS. Chrome is one example.

What's the most reliable solution which can accurately detect that the user is accessing to website via UIWebView, not mobile Safari?

With the evolution of UIWebView, something of UIWebView will be changed. I wanna know if there's a most reliable solution. Does Apple provide relevant solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

UIWebView IS mobile safari. If the user agent is the same you must treat it the same.